# How can I make a non-PRO Eye-fi transfer RAW files?

Tags: raw, file-transfer, eye-fi

I have an Eye-Fi card, and it looks like it's not the PRO series, and therefore not allowed to transfer RAW images. The card transfers JPG files without problem, but not RAW. If I rename a RAW file to JPG, it is transferred without any problems also.

Is it possible somehow make my Canon 6D save RAW files with extension of JPG or otherwise make my Eye-Fi transfer RAW files?

Answer (score 3):

I am with Eyefi and I would like to see if we can get this sorted out for you.

It sounds like you may have a standard Eyefi Mobi card. What color is your card and what is the GB capacity? If it's an orange 32GB card, its a standard Mobi card, which only transfers JPEG files via WiFi. If it's a black 32GB card, then it is an Eyefi Mobi Pro card and I would like you to speak with our support team if you're not seeing RAW files transfer wirelessly.

If have a moment, please contact support@eyefi.com.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Emily. It really sounds like vico is pretty clear that it's _not_ the pro version, but as discovered that it will transfer any file if it happens to be _named_ `.JPG`. The question is basically looking for hack to get around this. I assume that the limitation is basically artificial rather than technical, to help with market segmentation, and that therefore your support people are actually not really going to want to help. (Which, given the circumstances, seems fair enough.)

Comment: Hi mattdm. If you contact support@eyefi.com they will be able to help you with an upgrade path to Mobi Pro. It will either be discounted or free, it will depend on which card you're using and how long ago you purchased it. I don't have a suggestion regarding hacking the card, and our support team would probably suggest what you have already done- which is to rename the file to .jpg for transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look at the scripting capabilities of Magic Lantern (http://www.magiclantern.fm/). Magic Lantern runs on the 6D. The degree of automation (e.g. rename after each shot or bulk rename when script is manually run) depends on the abilities of the corresponding scripting engine. Unfortunately, this is no out-of-the-box solution, but at least a starting point.